# YouTube video won't play, shows zero length

Tags: video, youtube

A while ago I've uploaded a video that's about a minute long to YouTube. It's only accessible to those that have the URL. It used to play just fine. Now, when I go to play it, it immediately goes to the very end, as if the video finished playing (where YouTube shows other video suggestions), and shows a length of 0:00. I tried it on different machines, different browsers, privacy mode, etc - same result.

I know the video isn't deleted: I managed to play the video successfully by setting the quality to lowest, turning on automatic closed-captions and adding the video to a playlist (not sure which of these fixed the issue), but it doesn't help me, because obviously other people following my video link won't know they have to do these things.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have Adblock or similar installed?

Comment: No, I don't... By the way, I was able to solve this for now by applying a YouTube video editing effect (I think it was brightening) - after that, YouTube "re-processed" the video and it is now playing properly. Still, I would like to understand why this happened and how I can prevent it from happening again.